# null pData on aplet

Tags: java, null, applet

I have a Java applet from which I try to call `getContext().showDocument(aUrl)` to navigate to another web page. Although the browser correctly navigates to the new page, I keep getting this nasty exception in the Java Plugin Console:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException: null pData
    at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.getLocationOnScreen(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When calling the `showDocument()` method, the control is inside AWT's ***event dispatch thread*** and I reckon the exception is thrown when the new page is loaded before the ***event dispatch thread*** has finished processing the current event and the applet is already .

The exception seems to be harmless although I have noticed that when it gets thrown, the applet's `destroy()` method is not called anymore which theoretically can lead to problems.

A google search on this issue comes up with a lot of reports on similar problems but there is no clear solution. Has anybody got any idea how can I overcome this problem? Is this a known bug? Is there a quick fix or something?

Best regards,
Dan.

Answer (score 0):

[SwingUtilities' invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) might help you.
The idea is to deffer the call to show document after all the events were processed. Just create a Runnable instance with your code and invoke it.